# How to search on mongoose with exclude

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i have 2 Schema like bellow, i need to get 50 item from videoInfos which not have in userInfos.watched (this array content _id of videoInfos). Please use syntax like videoInfos.find().exce if you can.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    point: Number,
    watched: Array,//content _id of videoInfos
    running: Array,
});

const userInfos = mongoose.model('userInfos', userSchema);
//======================================================
const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner:String,
    videoID:String,
    totalTime: Number,
    totalView:Number,
    finish: Number,
    didFinish:Boolean,
});

const videoInfos = mongoose.model('videoInfos', videoSchema);
```

Comment: aggregation query syntax work for you?

Comment: i'm new in mongoose, any easy way is accept, coud you help me?

Comment: Do one CRUD project using mongoose. Then learn mongodb queries using aggregation pipeline or learn mongo operators and do some indexing stuff. Note: Don't use mongoose populate, its slow down your queries. Use aggregation $lookup instead of populate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mongoose you can achieve it like this.

Change the schema like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    point: Number,
    watched: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'videoInfos' }],
    running: Array,
});
```

And query like this:

```
userInfos.find({}).populate('watched');
```

The `watched` array should be populated with `videoInfo` data.

For more, take a look at [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: thanks, that so usefull, but i need to get item in videoInfos 'not have' in userInfos.watched . any easy way to do that?

Comment: The easiest way is to run 2 separate query. First get the user. Example: `const user = await userInfos.find({username: 'the_user' });` Then get videoInfo like this `videoInfos.find({ _id: { $in: [user. watched] } });`. Hope it helps.